# Dplyr : how to find the first-non missing string by groups?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following simple example

```
group <-c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
names<- c(NA,'fred',NA,'josh','josh',NA,NA)
data=data_frame(group,names)

> data
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  group names
  <chr> <chr>
1     A  <NA>
2     A  fred
3     A  <NA>
4     B  josh
5     B  josh
6     B  <NA>
7     B  <NA>
```

Here, I would like to get, for each `group` the first non missing name in `names`. How can I do that? The solution below using `coalesce` and `first` fail.

```
data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(first_non_missing = first(names),
                                    first_non_missing_alt = coalesce(names)) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  group names first_non_missing first_non_missing_alt
  <chr> <chr>             <chr>                 <chr>
1     A  <NA>              <NA>                  <NA>
2     A  fred              <NA>                  fred
3     A  <NA>              <NA>                  <NA>
4     B  josh              josh                  josh
5     B  josh              josh                  josh
6     B  <NA>              josh                  <NA>
7     B  <NA>              josh                  <NA>
```

Indeed, for group `A`, `first_non_missing` should be `fred` for all three observations..

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the expected result? Should the found name populate all values in a new variable in a given group?

Comment: yes its just a regular mutate. same size of original dataframe, and a new column that just repeats the first non missing string in `names` for each group

Comment: thanks buddy but someone was faster than you :D

Comment: Maybe use `na.omit`?  `data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(first_non_missing = na.omit(names)[1])`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Summarise will give one entry per group, here, finding the first non-missing using `which`

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(first_non_missing = names[which(!is.na(names))[1]])
```

gives

```
  group first_non_missing
  <chr>             <chr>
1     A              fred
2     B              josh
```

If you still want all of the rows, replace `summarise` with `mutate`.

Comment: yes that makes sense. Thanks! Besides, I dont know what `coalesce` is supposed to do given that it does not work here...

Comment: Glad it works. I believe that `coalesce` is designed to be used *across* columns, not within them. That is, if you had three `name` columns, it would return the first one with a non-missing value for each row.

Comment: It's utility is actually larger than you might suspect. Imagine a case where you had a form that allowed respondents to include their "preferred" name in addition to their first name. If you are addressing them, you want to use the preferred name, but only if it is included. So, you might create a column `data %>% mutate(toAddress = coalesce(preferred, first) )`