# R unbalanced data frame data cleaning

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My data frame looks like this:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4

T1 NA NA NA
NA a  NA NA
NA NA B  NA
NA NA NA b
T2 NA NA NA
NA NA C  NA
NA NA NA c
```

I want to have it like

```
c1 c2 c3 c4

T1 a  B b
T2 NA C c
```

I tried with something like the following, which I saw from another post, but I don't think it applies to my problem, any help please?

```
stri_list2matrix(lapply(., function(x) x[x!='NA']), fill='', byrow=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `zoo::na.locf` to fill the columns with the first non-NA value then just take the last row in each group determined by the first column.

```r
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- 
  data.frame(c1 = c("T1", NA, NA, NA, "T2", NA, NA),
             c2 = c(NA, "a", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
             c3 = c(NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, "C", NA), 
             c4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "b", NA, NA, "c"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 %>%
  mutate(c1 = na.locf(c1)) %>% 
  group_by(c1) %>%
  summarise_all(function(x) last(na.locf(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   c1    c2    c3    c4   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 T1    a     B     b    
#> 2 T2    <NA>  C     c
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Try running in a fresh vanilla session. I can't reproduce your error (which looks like the result of a typo)

Comment: I suspect some functions were masked. Great solution, +1.

Comment: I guess the `df1 %>% group_by(c1 = na.locf0(c1)) %>% summarise_all(~ last(na.locf0(.x)))` may be more compact

Comment: That's cool.  I didn't know you could assign variables in `group_by()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `lapply` from `base R`.  After looping over the columns of the dataset, remove the `NA` elements with `is.na` (returns a logical vector for subsetting).  Then, pad the `list` output with `NA` at the end based on the `max`imum `length` of list elements and `cbind`

```
lst1 <- lapply(df1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
#    c1   c2  c3  c4 
#[1,] "T1" "a" "B" "b"
#[2,] "T2" NA  "C" "c"
```

---

It can also done with `cbind.fill` from `rowr` and `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(rowr)
map(df1, ~ .x[!is.na(.x)]) %>%
    reduce(cbind.fill, fill = NA) %>%
    set_names(names(df1))
#  c1   c2 c3 c4
#1 T1    a  B  b
#2 T2 <NA>  C  c
```

---

Or by reshaping into 'long' format while dropping the rows and then reshape it back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
     pivot_longer(everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
     group_by(name) %>% 
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
     select(-rn)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  c1    c2    c3    c4   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 T1    a     B     b    
#2 T2    <NA>  C     c
```

---

Or with `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1)[, rn := seq_len(.N)], id.var = 'rn',
        na.rm = TRUE), rowid(variable) ~ variable, value.var = 'value')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c("T1", NA, NA, NA, "T2", NA, NA), c2 = c(NA, 
"a", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c3 = c(NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, "C", NA
), c4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "b", NA, NA, "c")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I like seeing all the approaches you generate.  A question on that first way (which uses do.call & cbind).  Does it work if T1-c1 is `NA`, while T2-c1 is "a".  Does the "a" get mis-assigned to "T1"?

Comment: @wibeasley  thank you.  If the column is all `NA` as well, it should work because we are assigning to length `df1$c1 <- NA;lst1 <- lapply(df1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]);do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))`  I guess that is what you meant right?

Comment: @wibeasley  Or use the same example you showed `df1$c1[c(1, 5)] <- c(NA, 'a')` then I get the first row as output `[1,] "a" "a" "B" "b"` and second row `[2,] NA  NA  "C" "c"`  Not clear how the positions should be matched based on the OP's example

Comment: Yea, there is some ambiguity.  I interpreted it like @Hugh, where the values of `c1` need to be carried forward.  For the scenario I'm describing, slide the value of "a" down to the bottom cell of `c2`.  "a" is still attributed to "T1", instead of "T2".  `df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c("T1", NA, NA, NA, "T2", NA, NA), c2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))`

Comment: @wibeasley  if that is the case, a group by as in your solution makes perfect sense.  I was also thinking in that direction, but the `lapply` in the OP's code was a distraction

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution (similar to [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010937/12158757))

```
dfout <- data.frame(lapply(l<-Map(na.omit,df),`length<-`,max(lengths(l))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  c1   c2 c3 c4
1 T1    a  B  b
2 T2 <NA>  C  c
```

Comment: depending on the OP's parameters, this might undesirably slide values into the wrong T1/T2 classification.  (@akrun explained it better in the comments following his post.)

Answer (score 1):

One approach involving `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map(.x = split.default(df, names(df)), ~ .x %>% filter(!is.na(.)) %>%
     rowid_to_column()) %>%
 reduce(left_join, by = "rowid") %>%
 select(-rowid)

  c1   c2 c3 c4
1 T1    a  B  b
2 T2 <NA>  C  c
```

Comment: See the comment's after @akrun's post.  This might classify like akrun's first approach, which may or may not be what the OP intended (it's tough to tell).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to

1. fill in the implied `c1` values with [`tidyr::fill()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html),
2. group by `c1`, and
3. find the first nonmissing value within that group.

```r
# Option 1
df1 %>% 
  tidyr::fill(c1) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(c1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(
    c2  = first_nonmissing(c2),
    c3  = first_nonmissing(c3),
    c4  = first_nonmissing(c4),
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

# Option 2
df1 %>% 
  tidyr::fill(c1) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(c1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize_at(
    .vars = c("c2", "c3", "c4"),
    .funs = first_nonmissing
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

# Option 3 -suggested by @tmfmnk.  Doesn't need `first_nonmissing()`
df1 %>% 
  tidyr::fill(c1) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(c1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize_at(
    .vars = c("c2", "c3", "c4"),
    .funs = ~ last(na.omit(.))
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  c1    c2    c3    c4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 T1    a     B     b    
2 T2    NA    C     c
```

The helper function is adapted from [Dplyr : how to find the first-non missing string by groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515180/dplyr-how-to-find-the-first-non-missing-string-by-groups/40515261#40515261).  This approach has worked well for me for a while, and [here's a revision](http://ouhscbbmc.github.io/OuhscMunge/reference/first_nonmissing.html) that accommodate a few more scenarios, which you might encounter if your real data is messier than the simplified one used in the example.

```r
first_nonmissing <- function(x) {
  x[which(!is.na(x))[1]]
}
```

*The `df1` definition is stolen from @akrun's post*.

Comment: You can perhaps make it a little bit more compact by using `df1 %>%
 fill(c1) %>%
 group_by(c1) %>%
 summarise_all(~ last(na.omit(.)))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk, I like how the helper function no longer needs to be defined.  I added it above.  I kept the `summarize_at()` (instead of `summarize_all()`) in case the OP's actual dataset has new columns that aren't collapsed in this way.  But maybe those columns should be dropped before getting to the `fill()` step.